# Best practice to avoid code repeating ( symfony2 )

Tags: php, oop, symfony

I've got four REST controllers with exact same six methods. The only difference between them is entity they're using.

I was thinking about some precedent abstract controller with those methods, and with one property which is going to be the entity of course. Each of the REST controllers is going to extend this abstract controller and only overwrite this property.

This is my idea, but I'm not sure whether it is the best practice, especially in Symfony2.

Comment: I think you can do it and not  problem for best practice but not familiar with `Symfony` tho.

Comment: Best practice is good to aim for but not to live by, as, even when you have a bundle that is pure to "best practice", it will be improved upon... as will best practice. Create the bundle\app as best you can and then improve with what you know as times goes by. Don't rely entirely on a best practice that you don't fully understand/believe in.

Comment: Have you tried with a non-abstract parent class?

Comment: and why should I try non-abstract?

Answer (score 0):

In an project I'm working on with Symfony2 and FOSRestBundle we have the exact same situation.

We managed to get everything into a base controller class that extends FOSRestController and which is extended by all the other controllers. If you are using sensio/framework-extra-bundle you don't even need to write the code to fetch a single entity. We are also using an hybrid configuration with both MySQL and Elastic Search and the base controller class implements methods to query ElasticSearch including ACL information so that the logic is mostly in the base controller.